# How to take FirstName and LastName in DropDown List

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

In controller I have this code and at this moment I have DropDown list just for firstname.

Code is here:

```
ViewBag.patnikID = new SelectList(db.tbl_patnici, "pID", "firstname");
```

And now I need some code like this:

```
ViewBag.patnikID = new SelectList(db.tbl_patnici, "pID", ("firstname" + "lastname"));
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your tbl_patnici class**

```
public class tbl_patnici
{
   public int pID { get; set; }
   public string firstname { get; set; }
   public string lastname { get; set; }
   //[NotMapped] If you use entityframework then you must use NotMapped attribute.
   public string fullname { get { return this.firstname + " " + this.lastname; } }
}

ViewBag.patnikID = new SelectList(db.tbl_patnici, "pID", "fullname");
```

Comment: Thanks to everyone, but @Murat ÖNER answer is best for me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you don't bind directly to the database source and instead bind to your own IEnumerable which has the properties you want. I often have a reusable "ListItem" class which has ID and Text properties and then use a function to populate the list with the data I want.

For example:

Create a new class:

```
public class ListItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Create a helper function:

```
public List<ListItem> GetList()
{
    // get "db" here.
    return db.tbl_patnici.Select(x => new ListItem {
        ID = x.pID,
        Text = x.firstname + " " + x.lastname
    });
}
```

Call it like so:

```
ViewBag.patnikID = new SelectList(GetList(), "ID", "Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.pID, new SelectList(db.tbl_patnici, "pID", Model.firstname + " " + Model.lastname, Model.pID), new { style = " width:260px" })
```